# Disabling all Form Elements in one go, simple?!?! not working

Tags: forms, element

Trying to execute a very simple script here that disables all form elements in one go.

function setDisabled() {
    var formEls = document.forms[0].elements;
    for (var i=0; i< formEls.length; i++) {
        formEls[i].disabled = true;
        alert('whatever');
    }
}

setDisabled();

error i'm getting is that the 'var formEls = document.forms[0].elements;' is undefined,
i've tried numerous variations on this syntax but nothing is working.

site is here:

http://www.harleymediation.com/confirm_work.php

Comment: That links works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i fixed. I had to put the script after the form rendered,

Comment: Just what I was in the process of typing up.  The form hadn't yet been declared, so it was undefined in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're calling setDisabled() inline.  Try removing that call and changing your body tag to:

```
<BODY onLoad="setDisabled()">
```